# Convertion from Sql server 2005 to Oracle 9i

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle9i, dbmigrate

I have devloped website using ASP and Sql Server 2005. I have not used any Stored Procedure and Views [All the queries are passed from the asp page]. Now i need to convert the database from SQL Server 2005 to Oracle 9i.

Will it takes huge changes in my code? Is there any tool to convert Sql Server 2005 query to Oracle query?

Answer (score 0):

This seems kind of hard to answer. You could have Sql server specific queries, or standardized queries. It will take some tweaking, but it shouldn't be too bad if your app is well designed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can answer that without knowing how your application is designed.  Did you build your data access tier or did you use an ORM?  Any user defined types?  Etc.

Here's an article I found on how to migrate a SQL 2005 database to Oracle 11g.  This may help by pointing you in the right direction.

http://st-curriculum.oracle.com/obe/db/hol08/sqldev_migration/mssqlserver/migrate_microsoft_sqlserver_otn.htm

**EDIT:**
Here's a [link](http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/) to a useful page that compares SQL Server and Oracle (along with a few other vendors') sql syntax.  This should be useful in helping you determine how much work will be required converting your app from using SQL Server to Oracle.

Comment: I have not build data access layer separately. But all the query related codes are within a single page (like Process.asp). I don't know much about oracle queries. In terms of sql statements (query) Is there major difference between Oracle and Sql server? (Like Joins i have used lots of join condition)

Comment: Added a link to my answer to a page that compares SQL syntax between MSFT, Oracle and a few other vendors.  This should be helpful in determining how easy your migration will be.

Answer (score 0):

exists tool in Oracle 9i to migrate from SQL Server [here it is a demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/sqlserver-083382.html)

[Oracle SQL Developer Migrations: Getting Started](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/migration/omwb-getstarted-093461.html)

if it is not enough tell me something .... i will migrate from 2k5 and 2k8 to 9i

------- edited

Check the following...

[Oracle Migration Workbench](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration/workbench/index.html)

[Oracle SQL Developer Migrations](http://www.oracle.com/technology/tech/migration//workbench/index_sqldev_omwb.html)